# problem with aspx url

Tags: asp.net

i m building website in asp.net 
when i run my pages
i expect that my brower should display url like this
http://www.fixpic.com/uploo.aspx

but instead of this it displays
http://www.fixpic.com/**(S(vqr0tz45005i2c450544ut45))**/uploo.aspx

what could be the reasons behind it,,might be coz i m trying to make sessions but if that is the case than how can i remove these long characters from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because url is used to track session id instead of cookies. This setting is normally configured in web.config by the [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx) element. If you use `cookieless="true"` it will use urls. Set it to `false` and cookies will be used.

Comment: you mean then it will use cookies to get the session id

Comment: Yes, it will set a cookie on the client that could look like this: `ASP.NET_SessionId=vqr0tz45005i2c450544ut45`.

Comment: ohh i got it,it means if cookieless=true,then cookies are not created and session id is retrieved from the url itself however if it is false then a separate cookie is created for and sessionid is retrieved from there.

Comment: thnx for the reply and making me understand:-)

Answer (score 1):

you have set it to use the url for sessions (cookieless) so this is the sessionid, you will see a line similar to the one vbelow, if you want to set the seesion back to cookies just remove the cookieless=true

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true"/>
```

Comment: if i add this line then would it make any difference in my code,i mean like would there be any problem making sessions

Comment: the client will need to allow cookies but thats about it i think, most browsers allow cookies by default i think